# NPM Script Conditions not working on windows but on Linux and Mac

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

The below NPM Script is working fine on Linux and MacOS but not working on windows.
I tried searching for some solution but couldn't find one!

```
"scripts": {
        "install-dependencies": "if [ ! -d node_modules ]; then npm install && npx npm-install-peers; fi",
},
```

The Error I get is :

```
> if [ -d node_modules ==false ]; then npm install && npx npm-install-peers; fi

-d was unexpected at this time.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Any way to make this working on windows systems as well?

Answer (score 1):

Windows command line is not equivalent to bash on other systems. You will need to install bash via something (like, say the bash that git ships with for windows), and invoke npm within that shell.

This package is also related, but again, will not solve the problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Followup from comments. Node.js *is* already compatible everywhere this code needs to run. So I recommend in the npm script command just using node to run a script.

```
{
  "install-dependencies": " node -e 'process.exit(require(`fs`).existsSync(`node_modules`) ? 0 : 1)' && echo 'succ'"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering to my query @catalyst
Is there any way to achive the same work?

Like - when user runs `npm run or something` then first it checks if `node_modules` directory is present. If it's present then execute something else otherwise execute `npm install && npx npm-install-peers`

Comment: @lazycipher I usually use `node -e` for this type of thing. Since node code is actually cross-compatible.

Comment: or just create a `scripts` directory where you put some node code which does it... cleaner that way. You can use the child_process module to run things.

Comment: Can you give me any example please?

Comment: @lazycipher note that `&&` should work normally in windows `cmd`. I added a sample

Comment: Thanks a lot @catalyst
I'll try this.